# How `jekyll` works with `pygments` locally on PC?

Tags: github, jekyll, pygments, github-pages

I'd like to create a project `gh-pages`, and i've installed `jekyll` and `pygments` locally.

But while the website launched, the code snippets displayed without any color but a background.

And even i pushed them into github, it also displayed without any color.

the address of my page is `http://leftstick.github.io/angularjs-requirejs-skeleton/`,

Can someone tell why it seems didn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use backticks (````) to highlight but it doesn't work. You'de better use **{% highlight JavaScript %}** tag.
This does the trick :

```
{% highlight JavaScript %}

    (function(require) {

        var baseUrl = '/';

        require.config({
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            paths: {
                //configure the path
            }
            //anything else, place it here if you need
        });

        var preloads = [];//place your preloads path ids here

        //Load all preload dependencies
        require(preloads, function() {
            require(['js/boot']);
        });

    }(require));

{% endhighlight %}
```